# checking the context of a .txt file in python: True, False

Tags: python

I have a .txt file with a single string in it. I want to open the file, check what the string is, and, depending on the result, change the file.

Here is how I am trying to make it work:

```
file = open('flag.txt', 'r+')
flagtext = file.read()
if flagtext == 'a':
  print('a')
elif flagtext == 'b':
  print('b')
  file.close()
  file = open('flag.txt', 'w+')
  file.write('a')
  file.close()
```

For some reason, this does not work, and in my troubleshooting, I found that, the content of the file (and flagtext) are never true for `flagtext == 'a'` or for `flagtext == 'b'`, even immediately after I've created the file to be just that letter.

I've tried both `file.read() == 'a'` and `flagtext == 'a'` and I can't get either of them to be true. I *think* it might be because the text file has a second line because if I just `print(file)` then the output is

```
a
```

But I've tried going in and manually deleting any rows after the text, but I can't seem to get it to stick.

And, in case all of this is a completely ass-backwards way of accomplishing what I want: here is my larger picture goal.

I have a python script that runs in the background. I want to be able to change it's behavior from outside the script. My idea was to have it be periodically checking the content of this text file, so I just need to change the text file to change the script behavior. If there is a better way of accomplishing that goal, I'd love to hear it.

Thanks

Comment: You've called your open file `file` but then you read from `flag`

Comment: Depending on the file and how you are handling newlines, `flagtext` may have the value `a\r`, `a\n`, or `a\r\n`, not `a`. Start with `print(repr(flagtext))` to see what you *do* have.

Comment: @bekelem Right, sorry, that's a mistake from trying to simplify the variable names from my actual script. I'll fix it in the question. That isn't the actual problem I'm having though

Comment: I don't know how your code is structured, but it would be more elegant if you had a variable (global variable or class variable for example) that was updated instead of updating a file with IO overhead.

Comment: `pdb` is your friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable's name is `file`, but you're reading the `flag` variable, change:

```
file = open('flag.txt', 'r+')
```

To:

```
flag = open('flag.txt', 'r+')
```

And, to ignore those trailing spaces/newlines, use `rstrip`:

```
flagtext = flag.read().rstrip()
```

Also, you should open your file using a context manager to avoid problems of missing to `close` the file (which is the case because in your `if` block, you're not closing the file):

```
with open('flag.txt', 'r+') as flag:
    flagtext = flag.read().rstrip()
...

with open('flag.txt', 'w+') as flag:
    flag.write('a')
```

In this way, the file will be automatically closed after exiting the `with` block.

Comment: Also, the recommended construction is with a context manager: `with open("flag.txt", "r+") as file: ...` and then you don't risk having a missing `file.close()` in your `elif` block.